# How to get a user's OAuth2/access token using Django allauth package

Tags: python, django, django-allauth, twitch-api

I am using django-allauth in my Django application, and my registration process is handled by Twitch, using allauth's Twitch provider. As of now, users can register on the website using Twitch, log out, and later log back in using Twitch with no problem. However, for making requests to some of [Twitch API endpoints](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication), I need the user's [Twitch access token](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication#types-of-tokens) to be able to make requests on their behalf (such as following a channel, etc.).
On a very old github issues page I came upon a question regarding how to access the user's access token and the [answer](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/122#issuecomment-8858551) was to query the SocialToken model and find the logged-in user and the desired provider. But in my case my SocialToken model is empty and there are no tokens to be seen there, and I have no clue how to proceed to populate the model and add every new user's access token there, so that I can make requests on their behalf, given I have the correct scope.

**Is there a way to add every new user's access token in SocialToken model? And is there a way to update the access token using the refresh token?**

P.S. I'm thinking about having a celery task that makes a request to Twitch API every time a new user registers, and later refreshes the access token when it expires. But that seems like a hack, and not really a viable solution, plus, I need a user to be redirected to a certain callback URI as per [Twitch API docs](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth/#oauth-authorization-code-flow) Maybe I'm just missing something.